# Discord JS Bot to recognize specific reaction add and reaction remove events on specific message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a Discord.js bot and, among other things, I want it to be able to post a message and keep track of how many :thumbsup: emojis are added as reactions. That is to say, I want it to count :thumbsup: emojis specifically, nothing else, and I want it to remove from the counter 1 point every time a :thumbsup: emoji is removed as a reaction.

I wrote the initial snippet for this feature some time ago, and the code I wrote for this feature no longer works, if indeed it ever completely did. I believe I was never able to get the reaction removal events to work properly. Recently I've discovered that even more than that, however, the reaction add event is being triggered for ALL emojis, not just the one I name here. I would be grateful for any assistance stackoverflow could offer in my efforts to make the following work as intended.

```
msgChat.send("MESSAGE CONTENT").then(msgElement => {
  const thumbFilter = (reaction) => { return reaction.emoji.name != 'thumbsup' };
  const thumbCounter = msgElement.createReactionCollector(thumbFilter, {dispose: true, time: 28800000 });
  var thumbCount = 0;
  thumbCounter.on('collect', (r, c) => {
    if (r.emoji.name == "thumbsup") {
      thumbCount++;
      if (thumbCount == 6) {
        msgChat.send("Six thumbs were gathered");
        thumbCounter.stop();
      }
    }
  });
  thumbCounter.on('remove', (r, c) => {
    if (r.emoji.name == "thumbsup") {
      thumbCount--;
    }
  });
  thumbCounter.on('end', (r, c) => {
    console.log("Collected " + thumbCount + " thumbs before closing");
  });
});
```

msgChat in this case is defined (correctly, as far as I can tell) to the channel in which I want the bot to post. Everything else in this snippet is constructed as best as I could from the online documentation of Discord.js. It seems to me, from what I've read, that the 'remove' event may no longer exist in the current version? But I have had a terrible time finding out how to replace its functionality.

EDIT: I have made some changes to my code according to advice below, and updated my Discord.js version to a modern version. I am happy to report that the remove event now appears to work as intended, but the filter, by which only thumbs up emojis should be considered, is still not working. Likewise, any reaction removal event is passing the filter.

```
msgChat.send("MESSAGE CONTENT").then(msgElement => {
            const thumbFilter = (reaction) => { return reaction.emoji.name === '' };
            const thumbCounter = testWarning.createReactionCollector({thumbFilter, dispose: true, time: 28800000 });
            var thumbCount = 0;
            thumbCounter.on('collect', (r) => {
                console.log("Collected thumbsup");
                thumbCount++;
                if (thumbCount == 6) {
                    msgChat.send("Six thumbs were gathered");
                    thumbCounter.stop();
                }
            });
            thumbCounter.on('remove', (r) => {
                console.log("removing thumbsup");
                thumbCount--;
            });
            thumbCounter.on('end', (thumbs) => {
                console.log("Collected " + thumbCount + " thumbs");
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does the `testWarning` variable mean here? I think you are supposed to create the reaction collector on the `msgElement` variable

Comment: You are correct, Caladan, thank you for catching that. I failed to correctly update that line for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use  instead of `thumbsup` and `===`(return `true` if `reaction.emoji.name` is equal to ) instead of `!=`. [v13 example from docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) and [v12 example from docs](https://v12.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector)

You don't need to check emojis inside the event listeners because you already filtered them.

```
msgChat.send("MESSAGE CONTENT").then(msgElement => {
    const thumbFilter = ( reaction ) => reaction.emoji.name === '';
    const thumbCounter = msgElement.createReactionCollector(thumbFilter, { dispose: true, time: 28800000 });
    var thumbCount = 0;
    thumbCounter.on('collect', () => {
        thumbCount++;
        if (thumbCount === 6) {
            msgChat.send("Six thumbs were gathered");
            thumbCounter.stop();
        }
    });
    thumbCounter.on('remove', () => {
        thumbCount--;
    });
    thumbCounter.on('end', () => {
        console.log("Collected " + thumbCount + " thumbs before closing");
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured that internal check wasn't necessary, but I thought it was worth adding in case it made a difference, which it didn't. I've removed those and replaced "thumbsup" with "" in checks of reaction.emoji.name, but it's still reading a successful collect when I add emojis that are not 

Comment: I tried again in versions 12 and 13. It works fine for me. Did you replace `!=` with `===`?

Comment: Foolishly, I had neglected to update the module. I'm trying to get it working order again as a v13 version now.